# What benefit does discriminating between local and global variables provide?

Tags: ruby, variables, global-variables, local-variables

I'm wondering what benefit discriminating between local and global variables provides. It seems to me that if everything were made a global variable, there would be a lot less confusion.

Wouldn't declaring everything a global variable result in fewer errors because one wouldn't mistakenly call a local variable in a global instance, thereby encountering fewer errors?

Where is my logic wrong on this?

Comment: Hint: encapsulation.

Comment: your entire program, potentially including thousands or hundreds of thousands of lines of code, spread across multiple libraries -- would have to make sure it never used the same variable name to mean different things, or overwrote a variable set in one place intended for one thing in a different place with a different intention. It is true that some of the very early programming languages had only global variables -- early versions of BASIC, COBOL, and Fortran. It is hard to write anything but very simple and short software this way. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable

Answer (score 1):

Some of this boils down to good coding practices.  Keeping variables local also means it becomes simpler to share code from one application to another without having to worry about code conflicts.  While its simpler to make everything global, getting into the habit of only using global variables when you actually have to will force you to code more efficiently and will make your code more structured.

Answer (score 1):

I think your key oversight is thinking that an error telling you a local variable doesn't exist is a bad thing - it isn't. You've made a mistake and ruby is telling you so. This type of mistake is usually easy to fix: you've misspelled something or you're using something that you forgot to create.

Global variables everywhere might remove those errors but they would replace them with a far harder set of errors to reason about: accidentally using a variable that another bit of code is using. Imagine if every time you called a function (one of your own or a standard library one or one from a gem) you had to check which global variables it might change (and which functions it called, since it might also change global variables) If you make a mistake then you might get an error message (if the class of the object in the variable changes enough) but often you would just silently get incorrect results (if the value of a variable you were using changes unexpectedly).

In general global variables are much harder to work with and people avoid them when possible.

Answer (score 1):

If all variables are global, every line of code in every program (including those which haven't been written yet) written by every programmer on the planet (including those who haven't been born yet or are already dead) must universally, uniquely agree on the names of variables. If you use a variable name that someone else on a different continent two years from now will also use, both of your programs will break, when used together.